# How to unit test a method with a Zend\Db\Sql\Select using PHPUnit in ZF2?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

In a Zend Framework 2 application I have a `Mapper` ([`ZfcBase\Mapper\AbstractDbMapper`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php)) class, that looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace AddressBookAPI\V1\Rest\Address;

use ZfcBase\Mapper\AbstractDbMapper;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet;

class AddressMapper extends AbstractDbMapper {

    protected $tableName = 'addresses';

    public function getTableName() {
        return $this->tableName;
    }
    public function setTableName($tableName) {
        $this->tableName = $tableName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function findAll($params = array()) {
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $select->where(
            isset($params['user_id']) ? ['user_id' => $params['user_id']] : []
        );
        $paginatorAdapter = $this->createPaginationAdapter($select);
        $collection = new AddressCollection($paginatorAdapter);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function findById($id) {
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $select->join('users', 'users.id = addresses.user_id', ['firstname', 'lastname']);
        $select->where(array(
            'addresses.id' => $id,
        ));
        $entity = $this->select($select)->current();
        return $entity;
    }

    protected function createPaginationAdapter(\Zend\Db\Sql\Select $select) {
        return new DbSelect(
            $select,
            $this->getDbAdapter(),
            $this->createHydratingResultSet()
        );
    }

    protected function createHydratingResultSet() {
        return new HydratingResultSet(
            $this->getHydrator(),
            $this->getEntityPrototype()
        );
    }

}
```

Now I'm writing unit tests for it:

```
<?php
use AddressBookAPI\V1\Rest\Address\AddressMapperFactory;
use AddressBookAPITest\Bootstrap;
use AddressBookAPI\V1\Rest\Address\AddressMapper;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use AddressBookAPI\V1\Rest\Address\AddressBookAPI\V1\Rest\Address;

class AddressMapperTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private $addressMapper;
    private $serviceManager;
    private $tableName;

    protected function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->addressMapper = new AddressMapper();
        $this->tableName = 'addresses';
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
        $this->serviceManager = null;
        $this->addressMapper = null;
        $this->tableName = null;
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function testGetTableName() {
        $reflectionObject = new ReflectionObject($this->addressMapper);
        $reflectionProperty = $reflectionObject->getProperty('tableName');
        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $reflectionProperty->setValue($this->addressMapper, $this->tableName);

        $this->assertSame($this->tableName, $this->addressMapper->getTableName());
    }

    public function testSetTableName() {
        $this->addressMapper->setTableName($this->tableName);
        $reflectionObject = new ReflectionObject($this->addressMapper);
        $reflectionProperty = $reflectionObject->getProperty('tableName');
        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);

        $this->assertSame($this->tableName, $reflectionProperty->getValue($this->addressMapper));        
    }

    public function testFindAll() {
        $this->markTestIncomplete( "findAll test not implemented" );
    }

    public function testFindById() {
        $this->markTestIncomplete( "findById test not implemented" );
    }
}
```

The problem is the testing of `findAll()` and `findById()`. Both these methods get a [`Zend\Db\Sql\Select`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php) over the [`ZfcBase\Mapper\AbstractDbMapper#getSelect(...)`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php#L94-L102).

Does it make sense to mock the `Select` (mocking then the `Mapper` with the `getSelect()` of the parent parent class)? **What and how should be mocked here?**